# Cruise Control .Net not showing Nant build errors

Tags: .net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, nant, nantcontrib

We are running Cruise Control 1.5.7256.1 and using it to do builds using Nant and Nantcontrib. The builds are failing and succeeding correctly, but when they fail the related error messages are being shown on the CCNet Build Report page. See image below

[image: No Errors!]

The build errors can be seen on the View Build Log page, but they aren't making it through to the Build Report page. The build itself is pretty simple, it's just a Nantcontrib msbuild element that builds a .Net 3.5 .sln file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you check the dashboard.config file? In this file you can add/delete xsl log parsers in the xslfileNames section like this :

```
<buildPlugins>
  <buildReportBuildPlugin>
    <xslFileNames>
        <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
        <xslFile>xsl\compile.xsl</xslFile>
        <xslFile>xsl\compile-msbuild.xsl</xslFile>
        <xslFile>xsl\unittests.xsl</xslFile>
        <xslFile>xsl\MsTestSummary.xsl</xslFile>
        <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>        
    </xslFileNames>
  </buildReportBuildPlugin>
  <...>
</buildPlugins>
```

If you want Nant outputs in your report, you must have the xsl\compile.xsl line.

You have a similar section in the server/ccnetservice.exe.config which is used for emails.

If you change something in webdashboard.config, you'll have to restart the whole iis to see the modifications.

Comment: I have the very same problem upgrading from cruise control .net 1.4, but I have all the xslFileNames needed, everything worked in the old server, moving to a new installation of CC.NET I do not see any error im Build report.

Comment: Did you check that your log file is correct and contains everything you would like to be filtered by xsls?