# Displaying results of an NUnit run, CruiseControl.Net 1.5.7256.1

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net

We recently upgraded CruiseControl.Net 1.4.2 to 1.5.7256.1. To our dismay the nice nunit results page that had previously been there had disappeared. All we get now is a build log with the verbose output from command line of our build.

After some research we discovered you can log into "Dashboard Administrator" from the main ccnet dashboard page and install the NUnit package. However, this did not change the output of our builds to include a NUnit result page.

Is there something extra we need to do here to have our output displayed? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't goto stack overflow until I've exhaustively searched on Google. I'm surprised no one else is confused or complaining about this.

FYI, we are merging our nunit XML output in the project configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not used to the Dashboard Administrator stuff, but you can [edit the `dashboard.config`](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuring+the+Web+Dashboard) manually. Opposite to earlier versions CCNET version 1.5 comes with a naked configuration file.

Alternatively you may simply replace the configuration file with your 1.4 `dashboard.config`.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Cruise Control .net: Using packages and showing NUnit results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728613/cruise-control-net-using-packages)

- Don't merge manually if you use the nunit task
- Edit the dashboard.config and the ccservice.exe.config files to add the nunit xsl files. Restart IIs.
- Check that the Iis user has been granted access to the dashboard dir.